# Unordered list in a table

Tags: tables, lists

I am trying to create a table with an unordered list in the last column. The problem with the code below is that it skips a line in each cell in that column just like the figure below. How can I create the table without having that skipped line?

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}



\centering

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{tabular}{ p{35mm} p{20mm} p{20mm} p{20mm} p{25mm} p{45mm}} 
 \hline
 & \centering Column \newline Number 2 & \centering Column \newline Number 3  & \centering Column \newline Number 4  & \centering Column \newline Number 5 & Column \newline Number 6  \\ 
 \hline

 entry1 & \centering entry2 & \centering entry3 & \centering entry4 & \centering entry5 &  \begin{itemize} \item entry6.1 \item  entry6.2 \end{itemize} \\ 

 entry1 & \centering entry2 & \centering entry3 & \centering entry4 & \centering entry5 &  \begin{itemize} \item entry6.1 \item  entry6.2 \end{itemize} \\  

 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some improvements and simplification (from a code by @Stefan Kottwitz):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem, etoolbox, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\centering

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, topsep=0pt, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\compress}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X *{3}{p{20mm}} p{25mm}p{45mm}}
 \toprule
 & \thead{Column \\ Number 2} & \thead{Column \\ Number 3} & \thead{Column \\ Number 4} & \thead{Column \\ Number 5} & \thead{Column \\ Number 6} \\
 \midrule

 entry1 & \centering entry2 & \centering entry3 & \centering entry4 & \centering entry5 & \begin{itemize} \item entry6.1 \item entry6.2 \end{itemize}
  \\

 entry1 & \centering entry2 & \centering entry3 & \centering entry4 & \centering entry5 &\begin{itemize} \item entry6.1 \item entry6.2 \end{itemize} \\

 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}



\centering

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{tabular}{ p{35mm} p{20mm} p{20mm} p{20mm} p{25mm} p{45mm}}
 \hline
 & \centering Column \newline Number 2 & \centering Column \newline Number 3  & \centering Column \newline Number 4  & \centering Column \newline Number 5 & Column \newline Number 6  \\
 \hline

 entry1 & \centering entry2 & \centering entry3 & \centering entry4 & \centering entry5 &  \makeatletter\@minipagetrue\begin{itemize} \item entry6.1 \item  entry6.2 \end{itemize} \\

 entry1 & \centering entry2 & \centering entry3 & \centering entry4 & \centering entry5 &  \makeatletter\@minipagetrue\begin{itemize} \item entry6.1 \item  entry6.2 \end{itemize} \\

 \hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]